# How to access input$... objects in a function when those input$... objects 'cannot' be supplied through an argument to the function

Tags: r, shiny

I need to call a function in my shiny app that pastes together the code that is to be executed.

(Why? I have many conditional inputs which are dynamically called upon to be worked with. Because of that the conditional inputs differ with the category selected in radiobuttons by the user.)

However, my app throws an error of "object 'input' not found".

Thus: How can my function access all the input$... variables?

**MWE:**

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

# Some function stitching together code =================================

my_function <- function(label_string) {
    # label_string is the string to the input i need to refer to via string evaluation (eval)

  out <- eval(parse(
    text =
      paste("tibble(testcolumn = c(input$", label_string, "))") 
# here it the reason for this issue. the label_string will vary with the
#  conditional inputs folding out. That is why I cannot just hardcode this part. 
#  (and this is the best solution I could come up with for this issue)
  ))
  return(out)
}



shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(

# this is some input I need to work with (in the real application these would fold     
#  out depending on the radioButton selection, but we don't need this additional 
#  layer of complexity for the issue at hand — how to access the input$... objects 
#  within a function when they are not supplied through arguments.

        radioButtons(
          "testinput", "This is just a testinput. Just select something.",
          c("A", "B", "C"), "A"
        )
      ),
      mainPanel(
        dataTableOutput("testoutput")
      )
    )
  ),
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    interim <- reactive({
      my_function("testinput")
    })

    output$testoutput <- renderDataTable(interim())


    # to be taken out when app is published
    session$onSessionEnded(stopApp)
  }
)
```

What is supposed to be generated is a table like this one (here it is shown for the case when "A" is selected)

```
# what is supposed to be rendered with all this.
tibble(testcolumn = c("A"))
```

Comment: Maybe `my_function <- function(label_string, input){......` and `my_function("testinput", input)`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried in my original work, didn't work. Should have tried it in the MWE. Thank you! (Now I feel stupid — Whoops) Thanks again.

Comment: thebilly, try `paste0` instead of `paste`. Because `paste` includes a white space.

Comment: Also you don't need eval-parse. You can do `tibble(testcolumn = c(input[[label_string]]))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(shiny)
library(tibble)

# Some function stitching together code =================================

my_function <- function(input, label_string) {
  tibble(testcolumn = c(input[[label_string]])) 
}



shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        
        radioButtons(
          "testinput", "This is just a testinput. Just select something.",
          c("A", "B", "C"), "A"
        )
      ),
      mainPanel(
        dataTableOutput("testoutput")
      )
    )
  ),
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    interim <- reactive({
      my_function(input, "testinput")
    })
    
    output$testoutput <- renderDataTable(interim())
    
  }
)
```